# PHP: Getting DOM elements by classname

Tags: php, html, dom

I have the following:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="content-top">bla</div>
<div class="inner text-inner">
bla bla bla
</div>
</div>
```

and the PHP:

```
 $page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/test');
 @$doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($page);
 $node = $doc->getElementById('content');
```

How can I modify `$node = $doc->getElementById('content');` so i can target `<div class="inner text-inner">` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use XPath to easily achieve it.

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/test');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);   

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='inner text-inner']");
$node = $nodeList->item(0);

// To check the result:
echo "<p>" . $node->nodeValue . "</p>";
```

This will output:

```
bla bla bla
```

Comment: When i try to save in a file // Record the entry
$record = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myfolder/' . 'test' . '.html';
$file = fopen($record,"w");
$txt = $doc->saveHtml($nodeList);
fwrite($file,$txt);
fclose($file);

it gets Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, object given in .. and nothing is saved in the test.html file

Comment: @Gorna-Bania that's because `$nodeList` is a DOMNodeList object. Try to change this: `$txt = $doc->saveHtml($nodeList->item(0));`